# Custom info window for google maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a custom info window for google maps.

I have sort of succeeded with one exception! Basically, the main info window is still visible and I have no idea how to remove it or hide it.

This is a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8yL2vhoe/)

And this is what I am following: [custom info window](http://en.marnoto.com/2014/09/5-formas-de-personalizar-infowindow.html)

I have this code as mentioned in the link above:

```
   // Reference to the DIV which receives the contents of the infowindow using jQuery
   var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

   /* The DIV we want to change is above the .gm-style-iw DIV.
    * So, we use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
    * and took advantage of the existing reference to .gm-style-iw for the previous DIV with .prev().
    */
   var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

   // Remove the background shadow DIV
   iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

   // Remove the white background DIV
   iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything as you can see in my Fiddle.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

I think I'm getting somewhere.

I've created a custom Function and put all the code for the removing the background in it. and then I call the `customFunction();` right after html='' stuff.

But the issue is that it won't work for the first click but it will work for second click or third click etc...

I've updated the [FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/8yL2vhoe/1/)

any suggestions?

**SECOND EDIT:**

Getting very close.

https://jsfiddle.net/8yL2vhoe/3/

If you click on one marker and then click on the second one you would see the result that I am looking for. (no background for the main popup).

I just don't understand why it doesn't work for the first click!!

Comment: Seems to work first time for me, what exactly isn't happening on the first click?

Comment: @DBS, I don't need the background for the main pop-up... if you click on one of the markers and then click on another one, you will see that the first info window background disappears which is what I want all the time.. hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see your updated [Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8yL2vhoe/8/).

Just move the `var html = "...";` and `var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({...})` outside of your marker's click listener.
The click listener for the marker could be made simpler as below:

```
var activeInfoWindow;
function infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url) { 
    var html = "...";
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({       
      content: html,            
      //maxWidth: 350           
    },customFunction()); 
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { 
            if (activeInfoWindow != null) activeInfoWindow.close();
            iw.open(map, marker);
            activeInfoWindow = iw;    
            customFunction();
    }); 
}
```

Also, your `createMarker()` function should be applied as

```
function geocodeAddress(locations, i) {
    var title = locations[i][0];
    var address = locations[i][1];
    var url = locations[i][2];
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': locations[i][1]
    },
    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            createMarker(results, url, title, address);
        } else {
            alert("geocode of " + address + " failed:" + status);
        }
    });
}
function createMarker(results, url, title, address) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: url,
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location,
      title: title,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      address: address,
      url: url
    }); 
    infoWindow(marker, map, title, address, url);
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);    
}
```